# Pluging with content for a specific page or post

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I'm new to writing WordPress plugins, and I'm running into a snag.  A lot of what I've seen is about using actions or filters to manipulate or add content at specific global areas (all posts, on post, etc).  What I'm looking for is how to create content for a specific page.  I haven't seen any tutorials that cover this.

Take, for instance, Contact Form 7 - you copy a specific string into a page body, and it triggers the content.  Are they just replacing the content using a filter?  I want to make sure there isn't an easier way to tackle this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're referring to a [shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).